# Not able to obtain image meta from CMSampleBuffer

Tags: ios, image, mono, xamarin.ios, avfoundation

I am trying to get the image meta data which is in sample buffer, following is the code snippet:

`stillImageOutput.CaptureStillImageAsynchronously (requiredConnection, (CMSampleBuffer imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError error) => { 
//Retrieving the image 
NSData imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.JpegStillToNSData (imageDataSampleBuffer); 
stillImage = new UIImage (imageData);
//      Not able to get alternative for the following Code, need to get exif/orientation metadata of the image 
//      CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment(imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL); } );`

Please be specific to Mono.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer on Xamarin Forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/45282#Comment_45282)

Thanks to Taylor for answering.
Must say its not a very neat approach.

Leaving it unanswered incase a better approach is available...